# Identify this half matte sleeve for ThunderStone Advance?

Tags: card-sleeves, thunderstone

I just more or less completed my Thunderstone Advance collection at a recent garage sale. My collection, previous to that, is not yet sleeved but the new addition to the family (ToR w/ CoB) is already sleeved with what appears to be UltraPro 2 5/8" x 3 5/8 sleeves. I know the make is UltraPro as it has the [hologram logo on the other side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYnEC.jpg) i.e side not pictured below.

The UltraPro site does not seem to have anything like this.

Some have a matte finish on one side like the one picture below. I would gather the intention is that you could have a glossy side or matte side facing you depending on preference? These do not feel like penny sleeves (which I did find in this dimension on Amazon) and I do not want those for this. I am having a hard time finding more of this dimension. These are larger than standard Magic the Gathering cards.

[image: Regular in sleeve]
[image: "back" face of card]

<sup>Click on images to embiggen</sup>

Comment: They appear to me to be Ultra Pro’s Pro-Matte sleeves in clear, which I myself use for certain things. One side is glossy, the other matte. And sleeves made for Magic will fit TA cards according to this thread: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/822554/card-sleeve-size

Comment: After talking with m FLGS they also came to that conclusion. @user30903 If you flesh that out into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for sleeve sizes for a game, the following links are

- https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/164572/card-sleeve-sizes-games
- https://www.maydaygames.com/pages/sleeves-by-game

Here is the [entry for Thunderstone Advanced: Numenera](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/164572/item/3186814#item3186814), other Thunderstone versions are listed below.

I realize you aren't asking about the game, as much as what product are your sleeves. This is meant for people who may stumble upon your question.